# Can Graphics.DrawImage draw a YV12 DIB?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, dib

I've inherited a C# .Net Windows Forms project which receives a Device Independent Bitmap (as an array of bytes) from a Managed pre-compiled DLL.  The C# code makes a dummy BMP file from the DIB so that it can create a Bitmap which can then be drawn using System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ms.Write(fileHeader, 0, fileHeader.Length);
    ms.Write(dibBuffer, 0, dibBuffer.Length);
    Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
    g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

This works when the DIB contains uncompressed pixel data but on some hardware, the pixel data is in YV12 format and Image.FromStream raises a System.ArgumentException which I think indicates that the underlying code (GDI+?) considers the BMP to be in an invalid or unsupported format.

In this scenario, the DIB's BITMAPINFOHEADER (first 40 bytes) has these values:

```
biSize: 40
biWidth:640
biHeight: 480
biPlanes: 1
biBitCount: 12
biCompression: 'YV12'
biSizeImage: 460800
biXPelsPerMeter: 0
biYPelsPerMeter: 0
biClrUsed: 0
biClrImportant: 0
```

1. Does the BMP format even support YV12?  I can't find any example
   images online.
2. Is there a different way of handling the DIB to make it suitable for
   DrawImage?  The above code seems to jump through hoops.

Comment: In YV12, the V(Cr) plane stride is half the Y stride, so nothing in GDI+ can handle it without manual resampling. I don't think GDI can handle it either without manual intervention. [Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk) can, of course. IIRC, ffmpeg has a library, `libw`-something (sorry, I don't remember the full name), that provides conversion functions; YV12 should be included (the 4:2:0 down-sampling format is relatively common).

Comment: @Jimi , thanks. No-one has contradicted you, so if you format your comment as an Answer, I can Accept it.